# Why does stoi/atoi provide me with a compiler error?

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, int

So I'm trying to convert a string (composed of a number) into digits and insert them digit by digit into a linked list.

However, when I try it I keep getting errors with the compiler.

I tried using `atoi` and `atoi.c_str()` or `stoi` but nothing seems to work.

```
string s = to_string(number_sum);

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
     list->val = atoi(s[i].c_str);
     list = list->next;
}
```

where list is my defined linked list, and has a int val to hold my number.

So if `s = 12345`, I want my linked list to be: `1->2->3->4->5`.

I tried `stoi(s[i])` as well, but not quite sure what the error is.

Comment: Because `s[i]` is a `char`, not a string. Try `list->val = s[i];`, (or `list->val = s[i] - '0';` if you need to "convert" from `char` to the corresponding `int` value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` and `stoi` convert a string into a `int`.  You are not doing that though.  What you want to do is convert a character into a `int`.  To do that you simply subtract `'0'` from the character in the string to get that character as an `int`.  That makes you code look like

```
string s = to_string(number_sum);

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
     list->val = s[i] - '0';
     list = list->next;
}
```